# How to add custom IAuthProvider with PKCE flow in msal for graphapi sdk

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, token

I have my GraphApiEngine class:

```
public class GraphApiEngine : IGraphApiEngine
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    private string _accessToken;

    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
    public string AuthCode { get; set; }

    public GraphApiEngine(ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());
        _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserAsync()
    {
        return await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("GetUserAsync returned null.");
    }
}
```

And I have my TokenProvider class where Im doing registration for token access:

```
 public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {

        public IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication;
        private const string clientId = "someguid";
        private const string tenantId = "common";
        private const string clientSecret = "somesecret";
        readonly string redirectUri = "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback";

        public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }

        public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                            .Create(clientId)
                            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
                            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                            .Build();

            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var result = await confidentialClientApplication
                                .AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, "")
                                .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
```

I registered both classes in program cs as scopped services:

```
services.AddScoped<IGraphApiEngine, GraphApiEngine>();
services.AddScoped<IAccessTokenProvider, TokenProvider>();
```

Now,

- how can I pass authCode to TokenProvider from my GraohEngineApi?
- Is it ok to register IAuthenticationProvider in ctor of engine?
- Also where I need to put distributed cache for storing into azure storage table?
- Also I need to refresh tokens when they are near expiration time (I think that MSAL does it by itself not sure though)
- I want to obtain just once a token and use it undefinately period of time.
- How MSAL takes care of multiple users? For example I give the authCOde for PKCE flow for one user, then in another second, I give authCode for another user, so on so on, can you suggests some improvements if any?

Thanks